# VBA editor converts Folder to folder and throws a datatype mismatch when I use the variable

Tags: vba

I have the following code

```
Dim fileSystemObject As New fileSystemObject
Dim sourceFolder As folder
Set sourceFolder = fileSystemObject.GetFolder(sourceFolderPath)
processFolder (sourceFolder)
```

And the processFolder procedure is declared as

```
Sub processFolder(folderToProcess As folder)
'Code here
End Sub
```

What I find strange is that whenever I type Folder with a capital 'F', VBA editor converts it to folder with a small 'f'. And I get a compile error message that there is type mismatch when I call the procedure. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses here;

```
processFolder (sourceFolder)
```

convert `sourceFolder` to a string which cannot be passed to something expecting a `Folder` so instead;

```
processFolder sourceFolder
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I already have initialized the filesystemobject in the declaration. I will update the code in the question to show the declaration.

Comment: Or you could use `Call processFolder(sourceFolder)` if you feel it looks better, as it's the same.

Comment: Can someone provide explanation of why VBA editor is converting the class names to lowercase?